# Polymorphism in the Data Access layer

Tags: design-patterns

I have inherited a large ASP.NET application, which contains classes that contain Business Logic and Data Logic together.  I am trying to refactor it as I go along.

I am thinking of creating a data access layer.  One thing that is confusing me is polymorphism in the DAL.  For example, if you have a student class and then a postgraduate and undergraduate class that inherit from them, then you can do this in the business logic layer:

```
Dim s1 As Student = New PostGraduate()
```

Is polymorphism ever used in the Data Access Layer? I have seen this question elsewhere and answerers say don't bother, just call the DAL function, however I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on how the data is represented wherever it is persisted.

For example, if you have a single table (assuming you're using a relational database) that contains all basic student data, with additional tables for post- and undergraduate students, then you might want to consider it.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I thought.  For example, if you had three classes i.e. Student, PostGraduate and Undergraduate, but only one table in the relational database then it would not be necessary.  If you had three tables then it would be necessary.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Can you answer the question in my last comment? Then I will mark the question as answered.

Comment: You can have a single table with all the basic info that all three student types share, with additional tables that apply only to postgraduates or undergraduates. Then again, DAL functions should be simple, with all logic handled by the business logic layer.

Comment: Are you saying that the BLL should not talk to the DLL polymopically?

Comment: @w0051977 It's getting a little too theoretical - can you illustrate with an example?